# Validating hadoops map output is really compressed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running a map/reduce job in hadoop with the following characteristics, let's see if I'm reading this correctly:

```
Counter                         Map
FILE: Number of bytes read      131,229,590,404
FILE: Number of bytes written   274,528,656,294 
HDFS: Number of bytes read      45,564,455,186
Map output records              303,345,304 
Spilled Records                 604,392,672
```

Based on the counters I see it output 300M records, and spilled 600M, this suggests to me that it took 2 full passes through the data to sort it. That should mean 45G read off HDFS, and then a write/read of the 45G for the 1st pass, and a write of the 45G for the 2nd pass through the sort.

```
mapred.compress.map.output  true
mapred.map.output.compression.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

2013-05-13 11:31:32,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 8 sorted segments
```

The numbers there are suspicious to me though, compressed, the data is about 45G, uncompressed it's somewhere around 130G. I'm wondering if I'm just reading these values wrong, or if I'm really writing out uncompressed map data in exactly the sequence described above.

Comment: I'd need to check the source, but it could be that the spilled output is not compressed, only the final merged segments are compressed